# Layer Toggling from Multiple Services

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am attempting to modify the Esri sample below that allows for layers of a dynamic server to be toggled on and off.  In my case I want to be able to toggle layers from multiple services.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm

My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Explicitly Create Map Service Layer List</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.2/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.2"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


      dojo.require("esri.map");


      var layer, map, visible = [];

      function init() {
        map = new esri.Map("map");

        var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(basemap);


        //Use the ImageParameters to set the visible layers in the map service during ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer construction.
        var imageParameters = new esri.layers.ImageParameters();
        imageParameters.layerIds = [0];
        imageParameters.layerOption = esri.layers.ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_SHOW;
        //can also be: LAYER_OPTION_EXCLUDE, LAYER_OPTION_HIDE, LAYER_OPTION_INCLUDE

        layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://dal-gisweb/ArcGIS/rest/services/XTX-Pipelines-New/MapServer", {"imageParameters":imageParameters});
        map.addLayer(layer);

        //Use the ImageParameters to set the visible layers in the OPPL map service during ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer construction.
        var OPPLimageParameters = new esri.layers.ImageParameters();
        OPPLimageParameters.layerIds = [0];
        OPPLimageParameters.layerOption = esri.layers.ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_SHOW;
        //can also be: LAYER_OPTION_EXCLUDE, LAYER_OPTION_HIDE, LAYER_OPTION_INCLUDE

        oppllayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://dal-gisweb/ArcGIS/rest/services/CompetitorAssets/MapServer", {"OPPLimageParameters":OPPLimageParameters});
        map.addLayer(oppllayer);
      }
//Sets up the ability for dynamic layers to be toggled.
      function updateLayerVisibility() {
        var inputs = dojo.query(".list_item"), input;
        //in this application layer 2 is always on.
        visible = [];
        for (var i=0, il=inputs.length; i<il; i++) {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
            visible.push(inputs[i].id);
          }
        }
        //if there aren't any layers visible set the array value to = -1
        if(visible.length === 0){
        visible.push(-1);
        }

        layer.setVisibleLayers(visible);
      }


//Sets up the ability for OPPL layers to be toggled.
    function updateOPPLLayerVisibility(){
        var inputs = dojo.query(".oppl_list_item"), input;
        //Placing layer numbers below will enforce them to be visible.
        visible = [];
        for (var i = 0, il = inputs.length; i < il; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].checked) {
                visible.push(inputs[i].id);
            }
        }
        //if there aren't any layers visible set the array value to = -1
        if(visible.length === 0){
        visible.push(-1);
        }

        oppllayer.setVisibleLayers(visible);

    }

      dojo.addOnLoad(init);
    </script>


  </head>
  <body class="claro">
  This sample loads an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer and presents check boxes for only the layers that should be toggled on and off by users.  <br />

    <b> OPPD: <span id="oppl"></b>
        <br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='oppl_item' checked='checked' id='0' value='0' onclick='updateOPPLLayerVisibility();' /> Transmission
        <br>
        </span><br />

    <b> XTX-Assets: <span id="xtx"></b>
        <br>
        <input type='checkbox'  class='list_item' checked='checked' id='0' value=0 onclick='updateLayerVisibility();'/> Offices
        <br>
        <br />

    <div id="map" class="claro" style="width:1200px; height:600px; border:1px solid #000;"></div>

    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.

-Mike

Updated:  I should point out that I am able to toggle layers from the "layer" service but not from the "oppllayer".  They turn off, but never back on.

Comment: Did the answer below fix the Update you had above? I am getting similar behavior.

Comment: Yes it did.  You might want to post your code in a new topic.  The group here is extremely help and very adept and finding problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `updateOPPLLayerVisibility()`, your dojo query does this:

```
var inputs = dojo.query(".oppl_list_item"), input;
```

But the checkbox is styled as `oppl_item` :

```
 <input type='checkbox' class='oppl_item' checked='checked' id='0' value='0' onclick='updateOPPLLayerVisibility();' /> Transmission
```

Try this:

```
var inputs = dojo.query(".oppl_item"), input;
```

Comment: Thanks mwalker, that solved it.  I really hate it when I spend days trying to figure something out and it turns out to be a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out this blog post and the sample they provide - I implemented the same code in a test site and it worked great:

[http://www.roktech.net/_blog/ROK_Blog/post/ArcGIS_Server_JS_API_-_Table_of_Contents_(TOC)_Example/](http://www.roktech.net/_blog/ROK_Blog/post/ArcGIS_Server_JS_API_-_Table_of_Contents_%28TOC%29_Example/)

Comment: This is a good example; but from what I have seen in our running system has issues with the later JSAPI updates and needs some additional tweaks.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I like what they have done here.  I will need to "borrow" some of their code.